# WordPress wp_remote_retrieve_body() returning empty but postman returns value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am experiencing odd behavior with the wp_remote_retrieve_body() function.

When making a post request, I am able to see the response correctly in POSTMan. The API returns only a string value.

However, for some reason, the wordpress function  wp_remote_retrieve_body()  does not work. I use wp_remote_post() for the post request. the POST Request works fine, however wp_remote_retrieve_body() does not return the body contents.

I reviewed the codex and found its implementation

```
function wp_remote_retrieve_body(&$response) {
    if ( is_wp_error($response) || ! isset($response['body']) )
        return '';

    return $response['body'];
}
```

I assumed there must be a mistake with my $response. Below is my code

```
$id_ref = 'noerror';
if ( is_wp_error($response) || ! isset($response['body']) ){
    $link_pos_id_ref = 'someerror';
}
```

I hoped that the variable would update itself to 'someerror'. It did. SO I further attempted to drill down to the issue -

```
$id_ref = 'noerror';
if ( is_wp_error($response)){
    $id_ref = 'weberror';
}

if(! isset($response['body']) ){
    $id_ref = 'isseterror';
}
```

This time however, the value did not change. It was still 'noerror' So I checked the value for $response['body'] and found that It did contain the string!

I verified that the response was a 200 OK. So at this point, I can use $response['body'] to get my string value, but I have no further ideas as to how to go about investing this issue.

Maybe its strange that the API is returning a simple string instead of a JSON? I really dont want to keep using  $response['body'] as I found like to keep good coding practices.

Comment: Can you show what a full `var_dump` of the response looks like?

Comment: at the moment, no. I do not have any debugging tools setup and this piece of execution is done in the wordpress API, so  var dump will not work

Comment: Hace You tried adding logs to the remote script? Did You check the remote server / php-fpm logs to see if there is any error on the upstream?

Comment: If the upstream server is some 3rd party service, have you tried changing you `wp_remote_post()` header (e.g. cookies, user agent) to match your postman request?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you were using the `'blocking' => false` parameter in your request `args` which makes the call asynchronous and thus doesn't return a response.

If you set `'blocking' => true` you will get a response.